# How to implement the Unix comand "dirname"?

Tags: c, unix, dirname

I have no idea how to make the code for this command.

I had something but is not working. I think is a problem at the exec.

Can someone make it work?

i'm a newbie in this field.

```
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<libgen.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<dirent.h>
#include<stdio.h>

void showArgs(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i;
    for (i=0;i<argc;i++) {
        printf("Argument is %s ",argv[i]);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
int isdir(const char *path) {
   struct stat statbuf;
   if (stat(path, &statbuf) != 0)
       return 0;
   return S_ISDIR(statbuf.st_mode);
}
printf("Program started... \n");
showArgs(argc, argv);
if(argc == 2)
{
    if(isdir(argv[1]))
    {
        printf("Calling dir with parameter\n");
        execl("dirname",argv[1],NULL);
    }else{
        printf("invalid dir name\n");
}
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What about this isn't working? What results are you seeing; what do you expect? Also, are you sure that simply calling the existing `dirname` program counts as implementing it?

Comment: It dose not print the `execl("dirname",argv[1],NULL); `

Comment: Does it print any other line of code? Generally your program will only print things you tell it to, like with the `printf` statements.

Comment: `isdir()` is defined and called in same `main()` function, it will not create any problem for you?

Comment: Why would you use `execl` to begin with to parse the last component of a path? `execX` replaces the current process. You could never make use of the information in the calling function. Further, simply parsing the last component or returning `'.'` if the string is `'/'` is fairly trivial and much more useful to the calling code.

Comment: Shelling out to `dirname` hardly counts as a way of implementing `dirname`, at least not in my book.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, ["it doesn't work"](http://idownvotedbecau.se/itsnotworking/).  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you're missing an argument to `execl()`. It should be:

```
execl("/usr/bin/dirname", "dirname", argv[1], (char*)NULL);
```

The first argument is the path to the command to execute, then the remaining arguments are the elements of the `argv` array. And `argv[0]` is the name of the command.

You can also use `execlp()`, which searches for the command using the `PATH` environment variable. Then the first argument can just be `"dirname"`. But you still need to repeat it in `argv[0]`.

Also, functions should not be defined inside other functions in C. The `isdir()` definition should be *before* `main()`, not inside it.